# Bash script to read a file and add the contents

Tags: bash

I have the following contents in the file, and I want to filter `Executor Deserialize Time` and add all the values to get the final result. How can I do that?

```
{"Event":"SparkListenerTaskEnd","Stage ID":0,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Task Type":"ShuffleMapTask","Task End Reason":{"Reason":"Success"},"Task Info":{"Task ID":29,"Index":29,"Attempt":0,"Launch Time":1453927221831,"Executor ID":"1","Host":"172.17.0.226","Locality":"ANY","Speculative":false,"Getting Result Time":0,"Finish Time":1453927230401,"Failed":false,"Accumulables":[]},"Task Metrics":{"Host Name":"172.17.0.226","Executor Deserialize Time":9,"Executor Run Time":8550,"Result Size":2258,"JVM GC Time":18,"Result Serialization Time":0,"Memory Bytes Spilled":0,"Disk Bytes Spilled":0,"Shuffle Write Metrics":{"Shuffle Bytes Written":0,"Shuffle Write Time":4425,"Shuffle Records Written":0},"Input Metrics":{"Data Read Method":"Hadoop","Bytes Read":134283264,"Records Read":100890}}}
{"Event":"SparkListenerTaskEnd","Stage ID":0,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Task Type":"ShuffleMapTask","Task End Reason":{"Reason":"Success"},"Task Info":{"Task ID":30,"Index":30,"Attempt":0,"Launch Time":1453927222232,"Executor ID":"1","Host":"172.17.0.226","Locality":"ANY","Speculative":false,"Getting Result Time":0,"Finish Time":1453927230493,"Failed":false,"Accumulables":[]},"Task Metrics":{"Host Name":"172.17.0.226","Executor Deserialize Time":7,"Executor Run Time":8244,"Result Size":2258,"JVM GC Time":16,"Result Serialization Time":0,"Memory Bytes Spilled":0,"Disk Bytes Spilled":0,"Shuffle Write Metrics":{"Shuffle Bytes Written":0,"Shuffle Write Time":4190,"Shuffle Records Written":0},"Input Metrics":{"Data Read Method":"Hadoop","Bytes Read":134283264,"Records Read":100886}}}
{"Event":"SparkListenerTaskEnd","Stage ID":0,"Stage Attempt ID":0,"Task Type":"ShuffleMapTask","Task End Reason":{"Reason":"Success"},"Task Info":{"Task ID":31,"Index":31,"Attempt":0,"Launch Time":1453927222796,"Executor ID":"1","Host":"172.17.0.226","Locality":"ANY","Speculative":false,"Getting Result Time":0,"Finish Time":1453927230638,"Failed":false,"Accumulables":[]},"Task Metrics":{"Host Name":"172.17.0.226","Executor Deserialize Time":5,"Executor Run Time":7826,"Result Size":2258,"JVM GC Time":18,"Result Serialization Time":0,"Memory Bytes Spilled":0,"Disk Bytes Spilled":0,"Shuffle Write Metrics":{"Shuffle Bytes Written":0,"Shuffle Write Time":3958,"Shuffle Records Written":0},"Input Metrics":{"Data Read Method":"Hadoop","Bytes Read":134283264,"Records Read":101004}}}
```

Comment: **Flexible and lightweight JSON processor:** [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor. **Query JSON data:** [Jshon](http://kmkeen.com/jshon/) parses, reads and creates JSON. It is designed to be as usable as possible from within the shell and replaces fragile adhoc parsers made from grep/sed/awk as well as heavyweight one-line parsers made from perl/python.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -P -o "Executor Deserialize Time.:[0-9]+" file.txt |
    cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

grep that bit the part of each line with the field you want.
Split it to just grab the number.
Use awk to sum up all the values

Comment: There is essentially *never* a need to pipe `grep` or `cut` to `awk`. `awk` can do those jobs itself.

Comment: What would the script be if one would like to sum the "Executor Deserialize Time" with "Stage ID":0 in the above example? There are other Stage IDs as well, like 1,2,5,8.

Comment: If you are going to be doing that, you probably want to consider parsing the json. I don't have experience with JSON and bash. I would use python if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v RS=, '/^"Executor Deserialize Time":/ {split($0,a,":"); tot+=a[2]} END{print tot}' file
```

- Set `RS` (the record separator) to `,`.
- Match records that match the desired field name.
- Split the current record on `:`.
- Add the second split field to our total.
- Print the total at the `END`.

Or same idea but set `FS` (the field separator) instead

```
awk -F , '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i ~ /^"Executor Deserialize Time":/) {split($i,a,":"); tot+=a[2]}}} END{print tot}' file
```

- Set `FS` to `,`.
- Loop over every field from `1` to `NF`.
- Match the desired fields.
- Split the current record on `:`.
- Add the second split field to our total.
- Print the total at the `END`.

If you only want this for a given value of `Stage ID` then you could use this:

```
awk -v stage=0 -F , '{
    ds=0; val=0
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        split($i,a,":")

        if (a[1] == "\"Executor Deserialize Time\"") {
            val=a[2]
        }

        if ((a[1] == "\"Stage ID\"") && (a[2] == stage)) {
            ds++
        }

        if (ds && val) {
            tot+=val
            next
        }
    }
}
END{print tot}' file
```

Which tracks whether we've seen the both necessary values for each line and only sums when we have. It uses the `stage` variable to do this so you can control this from outside the awk script (the `-v stage=0` argument).

Comment: What would the script be if one would like to sum the "Executor Deserialize Time" with "Stage ID":0 in the above example?